# How to drop columns of Pandas DataFrame with zero values in the last row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe which tells me monthly sales of items in shops
`df.head()`:

```
    ID      month   sold
0   150983  0       1.0
1   56520   0       13.0
2   56520   1       7.0
3   56520   2       13.0
4   56520   3       8.0
```

I want to remove all IDs where there were no sales last month. I.e. `month == 33 & sold == 0`. Doing the following

`unwanted_df = df[((df['month'] == 33) & (df['sold'] == 0.0))]`

I just get 46 rows, which is far too little. But nevermind, I would like to have the data in different format anyway. Pivoted version of above table is just what I want:

```
pivoted_df = df.pivot(index='month', columns = 'ID', values = 'sold').fillna(0)
pivoted_df.head()

ID  0   2   3   5   6   7   8   10  11  12  ... 214182  214185  214187  214190  214191  214192  214193  214195  214197  214199
month                                                                                   
0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
1   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
2   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 ... 0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
3   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
4   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 ... 0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

**Question.** How to remove columns with the value 0 in the last row in `pivoted_df`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with one line:

```
pivoted_df= pivoted_df.drop(pivoted_df.columns[pivoted_df.iloc[-1,:]==0],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove all IDs where there were no sales last month

You can first calculate the IDs satisfying your condition:

```
id_selected = df.loc[(df['month'] == 33) & (df['sold'] == 0), 'ID']
```

Then filter these from your dataframe via a Boolean mask:

```
df = df[~df['ID'].isin(id_selected)]
```

Finally, use `pd.pivot_table` with your filtered dataframe.

Comment: I also assume that if there is no data on sales last month, it means that there weren't any. Thus it is most natural to work on pivoted dataframe.